# Download attachments without browser

Tags: email, attachment, email-attachments, email-client

Does anybody know if it's possible to attach a big file to an e-mail and open it without opening a browser window? I mean, if I attach a small file, the file goes with the e-mail and I can open it without nothing more than the e-mail application. But when it's a big file (let's say 200Mb) normally I upload the file to an FTP, Dropbox, or other internet services. My client receives an e-mail with a link, and when he opens it, it starts a browser and he needs to click a link there to finally download the file. I would want to do that automatically, so my client only needs to click the link (or maybe drag'n drop) and it automatically downloads the attachment with no browser windows.

Do you think it's possible somehow? No problem if I need any programming language. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

It would imply the use of Javascript that's not allowed in mail clients.